dd clone disk to partition erased both drives
I wanted to clone a 4TB external hard drive (sda) to a 12TB internal hard drive with a hub (sdb1) and set up everything correctly until running dd in Putty with the command below. After about 20 minutes Putty spat out the error message when it disconnects along with a lot of messages about sectors I didn't copy (should've screenshot it). When I logged back into Putty both external drivers were missing from fdisk, lsusb didn't detect them, and they were missing from the disks page in OpenMediaVault (used it as a NAS). I thought I had no choice but to reboot the system, a RasPi, and the original drive's file system is back in OMV but wiped, and the new drive is missing a file system. I only lost some videos but still really ticked off. What did I do wrong? Are you not supposed to clone a disk to a partition? Was using Putty with a timeout a mistake? Something else?
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4K conv=noerror,sync



Are you not supposed to clone a disk to a partition?* You really aren't. Was using Putty with a timeout a mistake? YES.


/dev/sda should be unaffected. You didn't write to it


both external drivers were missing from fdisk, lsusb didn't detect them

Despite its name, dd doesn't delete disks from existence. It writes data to the disks – if a disk cannot handle some kind of data being written to it, that's a problem with the disk and not with the writer nor the data.
If a USB disk outright disappears from lsusb, that might be either a) power supply issues, especially if it is bus-powered, or b) unreliable USB connection, especially if it is USB 3.x which can lose connection just from signal degradation if you're using a too-long extension cable or something.
You should check dmesg to see what happened with it. (Unless you have already rebooted, in which case you should check the last boot's dmesg via journalctl -b -1 -k.)
While dd doesn't make any changes to the "input" file, it sounds like you were cloning it while it was still in use, which means there were likely some pending writes for /dev/sda that the OS hadn't flushed to disk yet – and which were lost when the disk became disconnected.
